# apt-get install python-software-properties dependency problems

Tags: apt, dependencies, add-apt-repository

So, I was trying to add a repository using add-apt-repository and I got this error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2
[sudo] password for foo: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 8, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
ImportError: No module named softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties
```

Like a n00b, I thought it would be a good idea to simply uninstall and reinstall python-software-properties using apt.

Upon reinstall, i got this:

```
foo@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libswscale0 linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic libtorque2 libavutil50
  libvtk5.4-qt3 fsl-mni-structural-atlas fsl-bangor-cerebellar-atlas
  fsl-atlases linux-headers-2.6.38-8 libnewmat10ldbl
  fsl-talairach-daemon-atlas fsl-harvard-oxford-atlases libgl2ps0 libcvaux2.1
  libgdchart-gd2-noxpm qt3-assistant liblapack3gf fsl-doc-4.1
  fsl-oxford-thalamic-connectivity-atlas libmysqlclient16 libavcodec52
  fslview-doc tcsh libhighgui2.1 libvtk5.4 libopenmpi1.3 fsl-mni152-templates
  fslview libqwt4c2 libcv2.1 libgsm1 libblas3gf libschroedinger-1.0-0
  libavformat52 libnuma1 libdc1394-22 qt3-doc libibverbs1 tk8.4 libpq5
  libgfortran3 fsl-jhu-dti-whitematter-atlas libva1 libqt3-mt
  fsl-juelich-histological-atlas libaudio2 mysql-common libnifti2 libmng1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up python-software-properties (0.80.9) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2327, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 2321, in main
    rv = action.run(global_options)
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 1493, in run
    runtimes = get_installed_runtimes()
  File "/usr/bin/pycentral", line 278, in get_installed_runtimes
    default_version = pyversions.default_version(version_only=True)
  File "/usr/share/pycentral-data/pyversions.py", line 172, in default_version
    raise ValueError, "/usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to %s" % debian_default
ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.7
dpkg: error processing python-software-properties (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon:
 python-aptdaemon depends on python-software-properties; however:
  Package python-software-properties is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
 aptdaemon depends on python-aptdaemon (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets:
 python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets depends on python-aptdaemon (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python-aptdaemon.gNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                             tk3widgets depends on python-aptdaemon (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon-gtk:
 python-aptdaemon-gtk depends on python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets is not configured yet.
 python-aptdaemon-gtk depends on python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon-gtk; however:
  Package python-aptdaemon-gtk is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on python-software-properties; however:
  Package python-software-properties is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-software-properties
 python-aptdaemon
 aptdaemon
 python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 python-aptdaemon-gtk
 software-center
 software-properties-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)                                         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             tk3widgets depends on python-aptdaemon (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-aptdaemon-gtk:
 python-aptdaemon-gtk depends on python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets is not configured yet.
 python-aptdaemon-gtk depends on python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (= 0.41+bzr646-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-aptdaemon-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package python-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on python-aptdaemon-gtk; however:
  Package python-aptdaemon-gtk is not configured yet.
 software-center depends on aptdaemon (>= 0.40); however:
  Package aptdaemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on python-software-properties; however:
  Package python-software-properties is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-software-properties
 python-aptdaemon
 aptdaemon
 python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 python-aptdaemon-gtk
 software-center
 software-properties-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?????? I don't want to reinstall python, as I have a lot of packages installed at this point...

Thanks a million,

tylerthemiler

EDIT:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/bin/

drwxrwxr-x  3  506   506    4096 2011-08-12 16:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root    69632 2011-08-31 18:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1  506   506      96 2011-08-12 15:59 2to3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1086 2011-08-12 16:00 apirst2html.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    65363 2011-08-12 16:06 ccache-swig
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      534 2011-08-12 16:11 ckeygen
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      532 2011-08-12 16:11 conch
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      197 2011-08-12 16:00 coverage
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      232 2011-08-12 16:00 cython
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      286 2011-08-12 16:31 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      294 2011-08-12 16:31 easy_install-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      204 2011-08-12 16:00 egginst
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      223 2011-08-12 16:00 endo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      228 2011-08-12 16:00 endo-readstate
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      206 2011-08-12 16:00 enpkg
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      197 2011-08-12 16:00 epydoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      197 2011-08-12 16:00 epydocgui
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      189 2011-08-12 16:11 ets
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      208 2011-08-12 16:00 ets3to4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      194 2011-08-12 16:11 ets-docs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      227 2011-08-12 16:00 ets_endo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      682 2011-08-12 16:05 f2py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     6737 2011-08-12 16:05 fitscheck
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      524 2011-08-12 16:11 flappclient
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      521 2011-08-12 16:11 flappserver
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      521 2011-08-12 16:11 flogtool
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      200 2011-08-12 16:09 fwrapc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    47003 2011-08-12 16:01 gif2h5
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      201 2011-08-12 16:01 grin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      203 2011-08-12 16:01 grind
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    40238 2011-08-12 16:01 h52gif
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     9494 2011-08-12 16:01 h5cc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   104953 2011-08-12 16:01 h5copy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    19508 2011-08-12 16:01 h5debug
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   196948 2011-08-12 16:01 h5diff
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   181410 2011-08-12 16:01 h5dump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    82444 2011-08-12 16:01 h5import
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    41356 2011-08-12 16:01 h5jam
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   131449 2011-08-12 16:01 h5ls
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   102923 2011-08-12 16:01 h5mkgrp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    75467 2011-08-12 16:01 h5perf_serial
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     4434 2011-08-12 16:01 h5redeploy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   157141 2011-08-12 16:01 h5repack
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    15762 2011-08-12 16:01 h5repart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   114276 2011-08-12 16:01 h5stat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    38241 2011-08-12 16:01 h5unjam
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      213 2011-08-12 16:08 helpviewer
-rwxr-xr-x  1  506   506      94 2011-08-12 15:59 idle
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      210 2011-08-12 16:08 img2png
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      209 2011-08-12 16:08 img2py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      210 2011-08-12 16:08 img2xpm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      253 2011-08-12 16:01 ipcluster
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      256 2011-08-12 16:01 ipcontroller
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      252 2011-08-12 16:01 ipengine
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      252 2011-08-12 16:01 iplogger
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      211 2011-08-12 16:01 iptest
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      250 2011-08-12 16:01 ipython
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      229 2011-08-12 16:01 ipython-qtconsole
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      208 2011-08-12 16:01 irunner
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      200 2011-08-12 16:06 isympy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      531 2011-08-12 16:11 lore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    24181 2011-08-12 16:07 lproj
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      590 2011-08-12 16:11 mailmail
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      579 2011-08-12 16:11 manhole
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      211 2011-08-12 16:10 mayavi2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    23353 2011-08-12 16:05 miniterm.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      591 2011-08-12 16:11 mktap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    10109 2011-08-12 16:10 nc3tonc4
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     4531 2011-08-12 16:10 nc4tonc3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      246 2011-08-12 16:11 nctoh5
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     4096 2011-08-12 16:55 nipy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      199 2011-08-12 16:04 nosetests
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      199 2011-08-12 16:04 nosetests-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      181 2011-08-12 16:36 parrec2nii
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2267 2011-08-12 16:05 pilconvert.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    15319 2011-08-12 16:05 pildriver.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2502 2011-08-12 16:05 pilfile.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      960 2011-08-12 16:05 pilfont.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2311 2011-08-12 16:05 pilprint.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      220 2011-08-12 16:11 ptdump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      222 2011-08-12 16:11 ptrepack
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      213 2011-08-12 16:01 pycolor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      207 2011-08-12 16:08 pycrust
-rwxr-xr-x  1  506   506      79 2011-08-12 15:59 pydoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      216 2011-08-12 16:05 pyflakes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      205 2011-08-12 16:05 pygmentize
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      538 2011-08-12 16:11 pyhtmlizer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      207 2011-08-12 16:08 pyshell
-rwxr-xr-x  2  506   506   10374 2011-08-12 15:59 python
-rwxr-xr-x  2  506   506   10374 2011-08-12 15:59 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1  506   506    1619 2011-08-12 15:59 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1  506   506      16 2011-07-05 19:46 python-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      206 2011-08-12 16:08 pywrap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      209 2011-08-12 16:08 pywxrc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1001 users   90834 2011-08-12 16:00 remove-EPD-7.1-2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      597 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2html.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      794 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2latex.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      603 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2man.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      730 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2newlatex.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1701 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2odt_prepstyles.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      767 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2odt.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      604 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2pseudoxml.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      640 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2s5.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      605 2011-08-12 16:00 rst2xml.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      673 2011-08-12 16:00 rstpep2html.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     6780 2011-08-12 16:06 scons
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     6780 2011-08-12 16:06 scons-2.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    16879 2011-08-12 16:06 sconsign
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    16879 2011-08-12 16:06 sconsign-2.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    50487 2011-08-12 16:06 scons-time
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    50487 2011-08-12 16:06 scons-time-2.0.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1  506   506   18542 2011-08-12 15:59 smtpd.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      220 2011-08-12 16:11 sphinx-autogen
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      195 2011-08-12 16:11 sphinx-build
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      206 2011-08-12 16:11 sphinx-quickstart
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1515029 2011-08-12 16:06 swig
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      528 2011-08-12 16:11 tap2deb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      615 2011-08-12 16:11 tap2rpm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      596 2011-08-12 16:11 tapconvert
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      534 2011-08-12 16:11 tkconch
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      670 2011-08-12 16:11 trial
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      208 2011-08-12 16:10 tvtk_doc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      607 2011-08-12 16:11 twistd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    20354 2011-08-12 16:07 vtkEncodeString
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4952419 2011-08-12 16:07 vtkpython
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   109429 2011-08-12 16:07 vtkWrapPython
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    10356 2011-08-12 16:07 vtkWrapPythonInit
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       41 2011-08-12 16:08 wx-config -> ../lib/wx/config/gtk2-unicode-release-2.8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        8 2011-08-12 16:08 wxrc -> wxrc-2.8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   101486 2011-08-12 16:08 wxrc-2.8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1627 2011-08-12 16:01 xml2-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      214 2011-08-12 16:08 xrced
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2450 2011-08-12 16:01 xslt-config
```

Comment: This seems rather serious: "ValueError: /usr/bin/python does not match the python default version. It must be reset to point to python2.7". How did you get to this? It would be interesting to see your sources.list

Comment: I just did sudo apt-get uninstall python-software-properties :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have done something else to change the version of the default Python interpreter.

The command `ls -l /usr/bin/python` should show something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2011-05-12 23:59 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

If does not point to `python2.7`, but `python3.2` for example, you modified the default Python interpreter to 3 which is not a good idea because of some backwards-incompatible changes. To restore python2.7, you have to run:

```
sudo ln -sf python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Only do this if /usr/bin/python is actually a symlink as visible in the `ls` output above.

Comment: foo@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2011-08-12 16:18 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/bin/python2.7

Comment: Pretty sure its pointed at the right place...

Comment: That's wrong, it should point to python2.7 (/usr/bin/python2.7), not /usr/bin/bin/python2.7. Did you do a custom installation of Python from source? Please post the outputs of: `python -c 'import sys; print sys.version'` ; `dpkg -S /usr/bin/bin/` ; `ls -la /usr/bin/bin/`

Comment: 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2]
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/bin.

Comment: I was having this same problem at home, and I tried this, and it fixed it: sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s python<your-version-number> /usr/bin/python Do you think it'd work here??

Comment: Did you try the `ln` command in my anwer? `-f` overwrites an existing file so the `rm` is unnecessary.

Comment: I am having the same error, I have done what's written above but the error persists, what could be the problem